# call fig from another function

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

hello this is a simple share of my code, i need to use the fig from func_1 in the code func_2.
im ploting some data, and need to extract fig to call it in func_2 so can use it in dash as test

```
def func_1():
              fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

def func_2():
              app = Dash(__name__)
              server = app.server
              app.layout = html.Div(children=[
              html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

              html.Div(children='''
              Dash: A web application framework for your data.
              '''), dcc.Graph(id='example-graph',
 figure=fig)])
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can't define a variable in a function and use it in other ones. You could either declare it at the top, which I wouldn't recommend, or  you can *return* it (code example given below).

```py
def func_1():
  fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
  return fig
def func_2:
  def func_2():
              app = Dash(__name__)
              server = app.server
              app.layout = html.Div(children=[
              html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

              html.Div(children='''
              Dash: A web application framework for your data.
              '''), dcc.Graph(id='example-graph',
 figure=func_1())])
#Above, you insert the function as a variable (passing in whatever the function returns)
```

Comment: Thanks for the Explanation and the code!!